# proving that $\arg\min f$ is also $\arg\min g\circ f$ for $g$ strictly increasing

Tags: proof-verification, optimization, maxima-minima

> Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a scritly increasing function. Let
>   $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. Prove that minimizing $f(x)$ is
>   equivalent to minimizing $g(f(x))$

My attempt:

$\min g(f(x))$ is a $x_0$ such that $g(f(x_0))\le g(f(x))$ for all $x$ close to $x_0$. Since $g$ is strictly increasing, $g(f(x_0))\le g(f(x))\implies f(x_0)\le f(x)$ for every $x$ in the ball. Therefore $x_0$ is also a minimum of $f$

Comment: There are two possible interpretations of your question. One of them is true, and one of them is false.

Comment: Also, it isn't just "for all $x$ close to $x_0$". That would be the local minimum.

Comment: I think the title is not good. The question is as in the yellow section.

Comment: I'm referring to the question in the yellow section. If the title is not good then you should edit it.

Comment: I edited your title.  Are you familiar with the notation $\arg\min f?$  It means the value of $x$ (the argument) at which $f(x)$ attains its minimum.